OpenSSL uninstalled but I get OpenSSL configuration error
I am in Windows/WSL Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. Even though I have uninstalled openssl I get the error
node: OpenSSL configuration error:
4048371EB67F0000:error:8000000D:system library:BIO_new_file:Permission denied:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf, rb)

What is caused this error?

*** EDIT ****
after update/upgrade
sdancer@AsusROG:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin gcc-13-base ubuntu-pro-client ubuntu-pro-client-l10n
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice apparmor apt apt-transport-https apt-utils avahi-daemon base-files bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu bolt bsdutils containerd.io cpio cpp-9 curl distro-info distro-info-data
  dns-root-data dnsmasq-base docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-scan-plugin fdisk fwupd fwupd-signed
  g++-9 gawk gcc-10-base gcc-11-base gcc-9 gcc-9-base gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 git git-man gitk gnome-shell gnome-shell-common grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common
  gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-x
  gtk-update-icon-cache iptables iputils-ping iputils-tracepath isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common klibc-utils kpartx
  krb5-locales less libaccountsservice0 libapparmor1 libapt-pkg6.0 libasan5 libasn1-8-heimdal libatomic1 libavahi-client3
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libbinutils libblkid1 libbluetooth3 libc-bin
  libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libcap2 libcap2-bin libcc1-0 libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libcups2 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libelf1
  libexpat1 libfdisk1 libflac8 libfprint-2-2 libfreetype6 libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin5 libgail-common libgail18 libgcc-9-dev
  libgcc-s1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data
  libgnutls30 libgomp1 libgpgme11 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common
  libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libip4tc2 libip6tc2 libitm1
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libjbig0 libk5crypto3 libklibc libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libksba8
  libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblsan0 libmount1 libmysqlclient21 libncurses-dev libncurses5-dev libncurses6 libncursesw6
  libndp0 libnetplan0 libnghttp2-14 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail
  libnginx-mod-stream libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 libnm0 libnspr4 libnss-systemd libnss3 libntfs-3g883
  libpam-cap libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam-systemd libpam0g libperl5.30 libpixman-1-0 libprocps8
  libprotobuf17 libpython3.8 libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libquadmath0 libroken18-heimdal librsvg2-2
  librsvg2-common libsmartcols1 libsndfile1 libsnmp-base libsnmp35 libsqlite3-0 libssh-4 libstdc++-9-dev libstdc++6
  libsystemd0 libtdb1 libtiff5 libtinfo6 libtsan0 libtss2-esys0 libubsan1 libudev1 libunwind8 libuuid1 libuv1 libvpx6
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwind0-heimdal libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-dev libx11-xcb1 libxml2 libxpm4
  libxtables12 linux-libc-dev locales login ltrace micro motd-news-config mount multipath-tools mysql-client-8.0
  mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-server mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0 ncurses-base ncurses-bin ncurses-term netplan.io
  network-manager nginx nginx-common nginx-core nmap nmap-common ntfs-3g open-iscsi open-vm-tools openssh-client
  openssh-server openssh-sftp-server openvpn passwd percona-release perl perl-base perl-modules-5.30 procps python-apt-common
  python3-apt python3-jinja2 python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools python3.8 python3.8-minimal rsync sosreport sudo
  systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd tar tcpdump tmux tzdata ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-drivers-common udev ufw unzip
  util-linux uuid-runtime vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny wget xserver-common xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg-legacy xvfb
  xwayland xxd
281 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
192 standard LTS security updates
Need to get 111 MB/317 MB of archives.
After this operation, 23.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 containerd.io amd64 1.6.16-1
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
Err:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-buildx-plugin amd64 0.10.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
Err:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce-cli amd64 5:23.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
Err:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce amd64 5:23.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
Err:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-ce-rootless-extras amd64 5:23.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
Err:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-compose-plugin amd64 2.16.0-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
Err:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 docker-scan-plugin amd64 0.23.0~ubuntu-focal
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.6.16-1_amd64.deb: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-buildx-plugin_0.10.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-cli_23.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_23.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-rootless-extras_23.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-compose-plugin_2.16.0-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-scan-plugin_0.23.0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb: No system certificates available. Try installing ca-certificates.
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.6.16-1_amd64.deb  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-buildx-plugin_0.10.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-cli_23.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_23.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-rootless-extras_23.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-compose-plugin_2.16.0-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal_amd64.deb  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/pool/stable/amd64/docker-scan-plugin_0.23.0~ubuntu-focal_amd64.deb  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 52.85.223.122 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

using sudo npm -v it works but the question remains.

First step is do a sudo apt update and a sudo apt upgrade. You are behind on updates according to the version info you gave.

@DavidDE it seems it failed to upgade

So that needs to be fixed first? Maybe you need a separate question with complete details and any errors you got to get help to fix that?

@DavidDE it seems that changing the permission to sudo chmod 655 /etc/ssl -R fixed the problem.
